# Axiom(s) of choice and bases of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, axiom-of-choice, vector-spaces

I'm not sure this question is more suitable for MO or for MSE, so feel free to move it to MSE if necessary.

I work here in ZF theory. Consider the following statements:

$(C)$ Axiom of choice: for any non empty family $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ of non empty subsets , there exists a function $f:I\to\displaystyle \bigcup_{i\in I}E_i$ such that $f(i)\in E_i$ for all $i\in I$

$(MC)$ Axiom of multiple choice: for any non empty family $(E_i)_{i\in I}$ of non empty subsets , there exists a function $f:I\to\displaystyle \mathscr{P}(\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i)$ such that $f(i)$ is a non empty finite subset of $E_i$ for all $i\in I$

$(B)$ for any field $K$, any $K$-vector space $E$ has a basis

$(G)$ For any field $K$ and any $K$-vector space $E$, any generating family of $E$ contains a basis.

In ZF, it is known that all these statements are equivalent.

I'm interested in writing a self-contained proof of $(B)\Longrightarrow  (C)$.

I've found two proofs in the literature: one is proving $(B)\Longrightarrow (MC)$, the other one is proving $(G)\Longrightarrow (C)$.

So, if I now how to prove $(MC)\Longrightarrow (C)$ or $(B)\Longrightarrow (G)$, I'm done.
Now, here comes my questions.

In all the references I found, the proofs of $(MC)\Longrightarrow (C)$ are drowned in the looong proof of the equivalence of 5 statements in ZF, but I couldn't find any direct proof. I'm not that familiar with non elementary set theory, and i'm not sure the effort I'll have to make to understand the proof of the equivalence of all these statements will worth it. So:

**Question 1.** Do you know a direct proof of $(MC)\Longrightarrow (C)$ in ZF ?

Moreover, I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that I can't find a direct proof of $(B)\Longrightarrow (G)$ in ZF. I thought it would be straightforward, but I can't find any proof for the moment. It's possible I'm missing an easy argument though. So :

**Question 2.** Do you know a direct proof of $(B)\Longrightarrow (G)$ in ZF ? 
Thanks in advance for your help !

**Edit.** After reading Asaf comment, I think I should say that I'm happy to include the axiom of regularity in ZF.

I reformulate my question: using ZF+regularity, can we find a direct proof of (MC) implies (C), or at least a proof which is more direct thatn the ones I've read in books (which are a chain of 4 implications, see my comment to Asaf answer).

Also, using ZF+regularity, can we find a proof of (B) implies (G) ?

Of course, I anticipate the the answers will be probably **NO**, but I prefer to make sure, before I choose to use a black box in my proof.

Comment: Would you mind giving a reference of $G\implies C$?

Comment: In $MC$, presumably you mean $f(i)$ to be non-empty?

Comment: Yes, of course. I edit my post right away.

Comment: Regarding Question 2, $(G)\Rightarrow(C)$ is much easier than $(B)\Rightarrow(C)$ (and I don't think it uses regularity, although IANAST). So I wouldn't expect a very simple direct proof of $(B)\Rightarrow(G)$.

Comment: Have you read my reply to your comment before making this edit? Regularity *is* an axiom of ZF. I just meant to imply that there is no naively simple proof. Which is what a lot of people would mean by "elementary".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no fully elementary proof that you are looking for. The reason is that the axiom of regularity is needed in these proofs. Multiple Choice does not imply Choice without it, and the only proofs we know about vector spaces go through Multiple Choice. While regularity is not a "difficult axiom" it does mean the proof makes some non-trivial use of the structure of the universe of set theory.

However, you can look in Jech's The Axiom of Choice, in the 9th chapter he covers the implication of $\sf MC\to AC$, and more.

Comment: How do you know it's not possible to have a fully elementary proof which would avoid multiple choice?

Comment: Have I said something remotely like that?

Comment: This is how I understood the first sentence, as there being no elementary proof of AC from existence of bases.

Comment: No, I meant there that there is no such proof from MC to AC.

Comment: And of course, there was quite some research into it, and so far no regularity free proof of bases to choice exists either.

Comment: @Asaf:  I'm ok to include the axiom of regularity in ZF. Btw, I still do not understand why using regularity would imply that there's no direct proof of (MC) implies (C).

I mean: Jech shows that (MC)=> every poset has a maximal antichain => every linearly ordered set can be well-ordered=> the power set of a well ordered set can be well ordered=> (C).
So let me reformulate: using ZF+regularity, can we have a direct proof (or a more direct proof) of (MC)=>(C) ?
It seems strange to me that the only existing proofs need to go through so many intermediate implications

Comment: My point out regularity is that it is not a "naive axiom". So any appeal to it means that the proof has to be somewhat convoluted. Not that Regularity is *not* part of ZF, because it most certainly is.

Comment: I think you can somewhat simplify Jech’s chain of implications by proving directly that (MC) implies that the power set of a well ordered set can be well ordered (using much the same argument, just not spelling out the intermediate steps).

Comment: @AsafKaragila : http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-08/S0002-9939-96-03305-9/  this article seems to claim they can prove AC from a weaker axiom, and in  a theory weaker than ZF, which doesn't include regularity - is there something I'm misunderstanding ?

Comment: @Max: The term "Weak ZF" is completely unjustified. This is just the standard system with atoms. Thing is you need to either replace Regularity with "there are so-and-so Quine atoms" or weaken Extensionality to allow non-set atoms. There's absolutely no need to do both.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : so this doesn't apply to ZF ?

Comment: @Max: I'm not sure what you mean. If you prove something in a weaker theory, it holds for the stronger one. The trick is that ZFA is *often* not weaker than ZF, because when you require the existence of atoms, you sort of "go a different route". In any case, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : you said that "Weak ZF" is unjustified, so I'm essentially asking if the theory used in the paper is actually weaker than ZF, and so, in particular, if the proof given there is valid in ZF ?

Comment: @Max: As you long as you don't *require* the existence of atoms, it's properly weaker. Usually implications are not using the existence of atoms, rather non-provability theorems do.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : ok so now my first question makes sense and I don't understand what you were trying to say earlier : since this is a proof that works in a theory without regularity, it seems to contradict your point "the only proofs we know about vector spaces go through Multiple Choice"; or am I still misunderstanding something ? (sorry if I'm being unclear)

Comment: @Max: It's not "those proofs", it's *one* specific example, not a general theorem. And certainly not a theorem that MC implies AC, because we know that this can be disproved—exactly when we actually *have* atoms.